# RequestError: Error: read ECONNRESET nodejs

Tags: node.js, api, request-promise

I try to use nba.com api, but give me that Error.

> "RequestError: Error: read ECONNRESET
>       at new RequestError (c:\Users\Omer\Desktop\game\node_modules\request-promise-core\lib\errors.js:14:15)
>       at Request.plumbing.callback (c:\Users\Omer\Desktop\game\node_modules\request-promise-core\lib\plumbing.js:87:29)
>       at Request.RP$callback [as _callback] (c:\Users\Omer\Desktop\game\node_modules\request-promise-core\lib\plumbing.js:46:31)
>       at self.callback (c:\Users\Omer\Desktop\game\node_modules\request\request.js:188:22)
>       at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
>       at Request.emit (events.js:211:7)
>       at Request.onRequestError (c:\Users\Omer\Desktop\game\node_modules\request\request.js:884:8)
>       at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
>       at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:211:7)
>       at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:387:9)
>       at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
>       at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:211:7)
>       at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:64:8)
>       at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
>   From previous event:
>       at Request.plumbing.init (c:\Users\Omer\Desktop\game\node_modules\request-promise-core\lib\plumbing.js:36:28)
>       at Request.RP$initInterceptor [as init] (c:\Users\Omer\Desktop\game\node_modules\request-promise-core\configure\request2.js:41:27)
>       at new Request (c:\Users\Omer\Desktop\game\node_modules\request\request.js:130:8)
>       at request (c:\Users\Omer\Desktop\game\node_modules\request\index.js:54:10)
>       at requestStats (c:\Users\Omer\Desktop\game\modules\utils\crawlers\stats\nba.stats.crawler.js:23:12)
>       at Object.crawl (c:\Users\Omer\Desktop\game\modules\utils\crawlers\stats\nba.stats.crawler.js:12:12)
>       at Object.crawl (c:\Users\Omer\Desktop\game\modules\utils\crawlers\stats\stats.crawler.js:20:20)
>       at Object.runCrawl (c:\Users\Omer\Desktop\game\modules\utils\crawlers\utils.crawler.js:27:18)
>       at startCrawl (c:\Users\Omer\Desktop\game\scripts\useful\crawl.js:19:13)
>       at loadConfig (c:\Users\Omer\Desktop\game\scripts\useful\crawl.js:12:5)
>       at c:\Users\Omer\Desktop\game\config\lib\mongoose.js:35:21
>       at 
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)"

That my code:

```
    var path = require('path'),
    request = require('request-promise'),
    format = require('string-template');

module.exports = {
    crawl: crawl
};

const STATS_NBA_API = 'http://stats.nba.com/stats/leaguegamelog?Counter=1000&DateFrom=&DateTo=&Direction=DESC&LeagueID=00&PlayerOrTeam=P&Season=2017-18&SeasonType=Regular+Season&Sorter=DATE';

function crawl(options){
    return requestStats(STATS_NBA_API)
        .then(statsPlayers => { return convertStatsToList(statsPlayers); })
        .catch(error => 
            console.log(error))
}

function convertStatsToList(statsPlayers){
    console.log(statsPlayers)
}

function requestStats(url){
    var options = {
        method: 'GET',
        url: url,
        json: true       
    };
    return request(options);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
   function requestStats(url) {
    var options = {
        method: 'GET',
        url: url,
        json: true,
        headers: {
            'Connection': 'keep-alive',
            'Accept-Encoding': '',
            'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8'
        }
    };
    return request(options);
}
```